# Apple in-app suscription screenshot review error

Tags: ios, react-native

for my react native ios app I created an in-app suscription, in order to submit it I have to upload a screenshot (what kind of screenshot is not specified, no dimensions given either).

I went ahead and took a screenshot of my Android device paywall screen (for ios I use a simulator).

I got an error message saying something like: You must upload a valid screenshot.

So, what is a valid screenshot?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the place in your app where the user can purchase your IAP, along with a description of how to get there. Using the simulator is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The list of accepted screenshots is located at: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications